# React.js and Django switching foreign key into name problem

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, react-hooks

I got `Game` model with 2 foreign keys `away_team` and `home_team`, both come from `Club` model. I got data from them rendered from the API to React.js like this:

```
const AllGames = () => {
    //Simplified Game object
    const [games, setGames] = useState([{
        away_score:"",
        away_team:"",
        home_score:"",
        home_team:"",
        id:''
    }]);

    //Simplified Club object
    const [clubs, setClubs] = useState([{
        name:'',
        id:""
    }])

    useEffect(() => {
        loadAllGames();
    },[])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        loadAllClubs();
    }, [games])

    const loadAllClubs = () => {
        getAllClubs()
        .then((data) => {
            setClubs(data)

        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    }


    const loadAllGames = () => {
        getAllGames()
        .then((data) => {
            setGames(data)
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    };
```

With this piece of code everything is loaded smoothly, the problem is when I try to render the data:

```
    return (
    <Base>
        {games.map((game) => {
            return (
                <p>
                  Home) {game.home_team}: {game.home_score} Away){game.away_team}: {game.away_score}
                </p>
            )
        })}
    </Base>
  )
}
export default AllGames;
```

The output looks like `Home) 1: 34 Away) 2: 51`  It displays id of the club instead of a name. I know there was a function to switch `game.home_team` and `game.away_team` from being id's to being proper names (aka: text variables like "Team Name Example")

TLDR; I need to swap `home_team` or `away_team` in games object list into `name` from club objects list with matching id something like if `games[1].home_team` === `clubs[1].id` then `games[1].home_team` = `clubs[1].name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a serializer method field in your django serializer. example

```
class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name=serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields =[
            "name",
            
            #add othe game properties
        ]
        
        def get_name(self,obj):
            return obj.home_team.name
```